# set text and image in button on c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a WinForms application. 
In the Main form I have some buttons and I want to add an image beside the text.

I set the background Image property to the image I want and on the FormLoad event
I set the image relation like that:

```
button1.TextImageRelation = TextImageRelation.ImageBeforeText;
```

so i was expecting to get something like a "list" when on the left side there is an image
and on the right side there is a text.

but all i'm getting now is the text on the center of the button and multiplicity of the image vertically and horizontally

Answer (score 3):

You should use [`Image`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.buttonbase.image.aspx) property of the button, not the `BackgroundImage`. The [`TextImageRelation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.buttonbase.textimagerelation.aspx) works with the [`Image`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.buttonbase.image.aspx) property.

This is an incorrect usage of `BackgroundImage`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved it by setting the BackgroundImageLayout to None

Comment: Keep it, others may wish to know how to solve the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do nothing with the FormLoad event. Just click the button you want to change image and text of and press F4, that will bring the properties window. find for text and set it to nothing i.e delete anything you find in the text. for image you need to find for image in properties window and then brouse your desired image. that's all